com.google.android.dialer cannot use ProtoDataStore backing without declarative registration
I have problem during pre-launch Android app on Google Playstore. My app made with flutter. I need release the app to meet Google Playstore rule that need update targetSdkVersion to 34. The issue is only happen in single device during Google internal testing. The device is Google Pixel 5 (Android 11 SDK 30). The error say that app crash due to this exception
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Config package com.google.android.libraries.performance.primes#com.google.android.dialer cannot use ProtoDataStore backing without declarative registration. See go/phenotype-android-integration#phenotype for more information.
  at qzc.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7664)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:947)
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: Config package com.google.android.libraries.performance.primes#com.google.android.dialer cannot use ProtoDataStore backing without declarative registration. See go/phenotype-android-integration#phenotype for more information.
  at qyh.run
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:462)
  at uao.c
  at tzp.run (PG:3)
  at uap.run
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:462)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:923)

I'm not sure how it can be happen because my app is not use any logic or package that contains "ProtoDataStore". This issue not happen during my internal team testing. I've try with Android emulator with same device type Google Pixel 5 (Android 11 SDK 30) and can't find any issue
My app use flutter sdk version sdk: '>=3.3.0 <4.0.0' and use some flutter package
flutter_inappwebview: ^6.0.0
permission_handler: ^11.0.1
flutter_background: ^1.2.0
flutter_webrtc: ^0.11.2
go_router: ^13.2.0
url_launcher: ^6.2.4
flutter_flavorizr: ^2.2.1
sentry_flutter: ^7.16.1
logger: ^2.0.2+1

Can I know somehow more details about why this issue happen?
I'm expect that there is more clue about the error
